# Vite with react - Browser error "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: jose"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, jsx

I'm trying to render an image with `JSX` but there's no image shown in the browser. I inspected the page and it returns this error on console "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: jose"

Here's the code:

```
import { jose } from "../img/react-logo.png";
export function Headerr() {
    return(
        <>
            <div className="redes">
                <img src={jose} alt="" />
            </div>
            <h1>Pizza</h1>
        </>
    )  
}
```

Comment: Google: "import images in vite". And then see the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html) from the results

Comment: Should `jose` really be in curly braces in your import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with static assets like images in *Vite*, there are multiple solutions available. One approach is to use the `new URL` function.

```js
export function Headerr() {
    const jose = new URL('../img/react-logo.png', import.meta.url).href

    return(
        <>
            <div className="redes">
                <img src={jose} alt="" />
            </div>
            <h1>Pizza</h1>
        </>
    )  
}
```

This approach allows you to dynamically generate the correct URL for the image based on the module's location.